# Regex - Validate Email Domain and Full email

Tags: ruby, regex

Here is the regex that I have:

```
\Ame\..*$
```

And I want it to match on:

```
me.com
me.ca
Bill@me.com
Bill.Smith@me.com
```

It also must not match on:

```
me.you@mean.com
me.you@foo
```

Currently it only matches the domain and not the full email.

I am using ruby for this.

I have been using http://rubular.com/ to try and solve this.

Comment: Check out Friedl'd [Mastering regular expressions](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565922570.do), it contains a regular expression for email addresses (it is several pages long!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following [works](http://rubular.com/r/CMdidWHtl1), if I understand your requirements correctly:

```
\bme\.[^.@]*\z
```

**Explanation:**

```
\b     # Match the start of a word
me     # Match "me"
\.     # Match "."
[^.@]* # Match any string unless it contains a "." or a "@"
\z     # Match the end of the string
```

(I used `\z` instead of `$` as I did on the Rubular example because that also matches the end of a line).

Comment: can you also make it not match me.you@foo